# IPhone / IPad development : possible to code "outside the app"?

Tags: ios

Sorry in advance for those who find that my title is not precise enough. If someone finds a better way of titling the post, be my guest:) The idea is that I am someone that learns through ideas and projects. Not through books. I learned PHP,HTML,CSS,JQuery... by myself through things I wanted to realize... Whatever... So now I have an idea for an IPhone/Ipad app. I know I have to dig into Objective-C. But before doing this I wanted to know if it is possible to build "outside the app". What I mean by that is for instance when you highlight text from safari in the iphone you get a bubble with "copy" written. Is it possible to have for instance a second choice called "whatever" that will send the highlighted text to the app I developped. I don't want to know how to do it. If it is possible i will figure out by myself. I just want to know if it is possible? Thank you in advance. Cheers. Marc

Comment: It's not possible, at least not without jailbreaking.

Comment: Thank you andrew. Is this a definite and 100% sure answer?

Comment: Why a downgrade ???? Little explanation would be nice

Comment: Yes, it's a definite and 100% sure answer. There are simply currently no public APIs for system-wide plugins and the like. Additionally, regular apps are sandboxed, which limits their ability to do anything outside their own sandbox container, and there are tight restrictions on what apps can do while in the background. (None of this precludes Apple from changing things in the future, but I'd be very surprised if they did.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want sounds like system-wide plugins and is possible by jailbreaking the device and using MobileSubstrate. AppStore apps, however, cannot benefit from this.

Comment: Thks H2CO3 dude... Pinguin... :)